# Calculating support using apriori algorithm

Tags: apriori

If we have the following transactions

```
Trans Itemsets
1     1,3,3
2     2,2
```

is the support for {2} = 2 
and support for {3} =2 or do we remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

No, it removes the duplicates, so it becomes
Support for {2} = 1
and Support for {3} = 1